Overwrite colors of bulma 1.0.X
I just begin to work on Bulma CSS 1.X, and after a lot of google search and pain, I'm unavailable to find a way of customing theme colors.
Based on the documentation I successfully edit this :
<section class="section columns is-8">
    <div class="column">
        <h1 class="title has-text-primary">Title</h1>
        <p class="article__preview">
            blabla
        </p>
        <button class="button is-primary">
            Lire la suite
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts column has-background-warning is-one-third">
        <div class="container">
            Contacts
        </div>
   </div>
</section>

@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@1.0.2/css/bulma.min.css";

:root {

    /*  =============== BULMA ============ */
    /*  PRIMARY */
  --bulma-primary-h: 280;
  --bulma-primary-s: 100%;
  --bulma-primary-l: 50%;

  /*!* TEXT MAIN *!*/
  --bulma-text-h: 0;
  --bulma-text-s: 0%;
  --bulma-text-l: 0%;

  /* EXAMPLE OF NOT WORKING */
  --bulma-button-color-l: 100%;
}

But this is just pain to do that. I am unable to just change button color text, I need to select .button to color: #fff. If I edit vars of color value of button, nothing happen.
Is someone successful to custom primary color (I want to replace this green/blue). I saw generators but not working on recent version of Bulma.

Just, in the code you showed, you missed a < for the h1 tag

`:root {
--button-primary-color: #fff;
}
.button.is-primary {
color: var(--button-primary-color);
}
`
try this

My issue is that i don't want to do that for earch item with is-primary at hand, i want edit root variables to don't care about adding new components colors.
